# Optimize Query with huge NOT IN Statement

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to find the sourcesites that ONLY exist before a certain timestamp. This query seems very poor for the job. Any idea how to optimize or an index that might improve?

```
select distinct sourcesite 
  from contentmeta 
  where timestamp <= '2011-03-15'
  and sourcesite not in (
    select distinct sourcesite 
      from contentmeta 
      where timestamp>'2011-03-15'
  );
```

There is an index on sourcesite and timestamp, but query still takes a long time

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select distinct sourcesite from contentmeta where timestamp <= '2011-03-15' and sourcesite not in (select distinct sourcesite from contentmeta where timestamp>'2011-03-15');
+----+--------------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | type           | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                           |
+----+--------------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | contentmeta | index          | NULL          | sitetime | 14      | NULL | 725697 | Using where; Using index                        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | contentmeta | index_subquery | sitetime      | sitetime | 5       | func |     48 | Using index; Using where; Full scan on NULL key |
+----+--------------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subquery doesn't need the DISTINCT, and the WHERE clause on the outer query is not needed either, since you are already filtering by the NOT IN.

Try:

```
select distinct sourcesite
from contentmeta
where sourcesite not in (
    select sourcesite
    from contentmeta
    where timestamp > '2011-03-15'
);
```

Comment: this can be done without 'Not IN'. since it is one of the most costly mysql operation

Comment: @MoyedAnsari: `NOT IN` is not the "most costly" operation. And this question needs either `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` subquery or a `LEFT JOIN - IS NULL` query.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.sourcesite
FROM contentmeta c1
LEFT JOIN contentmeta c2
  ON c2.sourcesite = c1.sourcesite
  AND c2.timestamp > '2011-03-15'
WHERE c1.timestamp <= '2011-03-15'
  AND c2.sourcesite IS NULL
```

For optimum performance, have a multi-column index on contentmeta (`sourcesite`, `timestamp`).

Generally, joins perform better than subqueries because derived tables cannot utilize indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I find that "not in" just doesn't optimize well across many databases.  Use a `left outer join` instead:

```
select distinct sourcesite 
from contentmeta cm 
left outer join
(
   select distinct sourcesite
   from contentmeta
   where timestamp>'2011-03-15'
) t
  on cm.sourcesite = t.sourcesite
where timestamp <= '2011-03-15' and t.sourcesite is null
```

This assumes that `sourcesite` is never null.